# Adding unique key before duplicate JSON keys

Tags: python, json, string, formatting

I have the following JSON string:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "comment":"hello"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "comment":"hi"
   }
]
```

I'm trying to make it like this:

```
[
   {
      "finding-1":{
         "id":"1",
         "comment":"hello"
      }
   },
   {
      "finding-2":{
         "id":"2",
         "comment":"hi"
      }
   }
]
```

What is the cleanest way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```py
j = [
   {
      "id":"1",
      "comment":"hello"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "comment":"hi"
   }
]

n = [{f'finding-{d["id"]}': d} for d in j]
# [{'finding-1': {'comment': 'hello', 'id': '1'}}, {'finding-2': {'comment': 'hi', 'id': '2'}}]
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I do this using a seperate integer instead of the existing id key though? e.g. {f'finding-{i}'} where i is an incrementing index for each finding-x

Comment: Take a look at the [enumerate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) function.

Something like this: `n = [{f'finding-{i}': d} for i, d in enumerate(j)]`